# How to approximate pre-self-insert-hook (which doesn't exist)?

Tags: elisp, hooks, self-insert-command

**Q:** how does one approximate the functionality of the non-existent `pre-self-insert-hook`?

This question is inspired by the curiosity that is the combination of `abbrev-mode` and `self-insert-command`.  The docstring for the latter:

> Insert the character you type.
>
> Whichever character you type to run this command is inserted.
>   Before insertion, `expand-abbrev` is executed if the inserted character does
>   not have word syntax and the previous character in the buffer does.
>   After insertion, the value of `auto-fill-function` is called if the
>   `auto-fill-chars` table has a non-nil value for the inserted character.
>   At the end, it runs `post-self-insert-hook`.

It looks to be the case that the call to `expand-abbrev` is baked directly into `self-insert-command` -- I assume for efficiency reasons, because it is ancient, or both (feel free to comment if you happen to know why).  Ordinarily, I would have expected such a function to run via a hook.  However, although there is a `post-self-insert-hook`, there is no `pre-self-insert-hook`.

*In the absence of such a hook, how does one approximate that functionality, and, more importantly, do so with a minimum of fuss?*

None of the options I can think of are ideal:

- advice: `self-insert-command` is [a primitive defined in C and therefore ignores advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Named-Functions.html)
- pre-command-hook: simple, but it's overkill because it runs before *every* command, and not just `self-insert-command`, and one may only want to run the command as part of `self-insert-command`
- define a wrapper around `self-insert-command`: this appears to be what `org-mode` and `smartparens` do (with `org-self-insert-command` and `sp--self-insert-command`), but seems complicated by the fact that a) you'd need to rebind an awful lot of keys to use it, b) if one uses multiple major or minor modes that use their own wrapper functions, one needs to keep track of fallback functions so that one does not lose the functionality of other wrappers when rebinding keys (at least I think so; I'm not so sure I understand this part).

Comment: Actually, it's not **so** ancient. It was apparently added in Emacs 23. Dunno why. Seems like `self-insert-command` should only, well, self-insert... You might want to ask `emacs-devel@gnu.org` your question (and why `self-insert-command` does `expand-abbrev`).

Comment: Well, you *used to be able to advise primitives* defined in C. (On n'arrete pas le progres.) You can still, however, advise `expand-abbrev` - does that help?

Comment: Define a new input method? I mean, you could define an input method to use your function before self-inserting command, so that would be equivalent to having a `before-` hook.

Comment: You *can* advise functions *defined* in C, but the advice won't apply if it's *called* from C.

Comment: @dan (thinking out loud) What about an input-method?

Comment: Fiddling about with `self-insert-command` directly will not work. Section `23.3.2 Keymaps and Minor Modes` of the manual states: `Do not try substituting your own definition of `self-insert-command' for the standard one.  The editor command loop handles this function specially.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can advise `self-insert-command` just fine.  In older Emacsen, it was sometimes (often) called directly from C, but since Emacs-24 (IIRC) it's never called directly from C, so the advice should work reliably.